# Android REST Client using Volley

Tags: android, rest, android-volley

I'm new to Android and wanting to build an Android app that is a Jira client. I want a login form that takes in the same credentials as our Jira server.

I'm trying to implement this using Volley, and would like to setup a singleton to handle all requests, and another singleton for user credentials.

Do I need any other library than Volley?
Is this possible? If not, why?

Could anyone please provide some example or point me to a tutorial that does this sort of thing? I've searched for hours and can't really find anything that helps so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, volley is sufficient for all network related operations. You can create a singleton for API requests and abstract all logic from rest of application. [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) article guides through the implementation steps really well.